# Dice-Probability with greater than first four

Tags: probability

[image]
To answer this question I need to find out the probability of the numbers 5 and 6. and that is $\frac23$.Now what step will be the next?  Do I have to find out the first four probability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that the first $5$ of $6$ is rolled on the third or fourth roll is equal to the probability that either the first roll is less than or equal to $4$, the second roll is less than or equal to $4$, and the third roll is greater than $4$, or that the first three rolls are all less than $4$, and the fourth is greater than $4$.

The probability that a die rolls less than or equal to $4$ (equivalently, the probability that it lands on $1,2,3,$ or $4$) is $4{\over6}={2\over3}$, and the probability that it is more than $4$ (equivalently, the probability that it lands on $5$ or $6$) is ${2\over6}={1\over3}$ (not $2\over3$ as you said in the question).

So, to find the probability of the first of the listed possibilities, we multiply: the probability that the first two are less than or equal to four, and the third is greater than four, is ${2\over3}\cdot{2\over3}\cdot{1\over3}={4\over27}$

For the second possibility, that the first three rolls are less than or equal to four, and the fourth is greater, we also multiply, getting ${2\over3}\cdot{2\over3}\cdot{2\over3}\cdot{1\over3}={8\over81}$.

Since these events are mutually exclusive, we can add these probabilities to find the overall probability: $P={4\over27}+{8\over81}={20\over81}$.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of greater than 4 occurring on the third roll is the probability of failures in the first two and a success on the third roll: $P(N=3) = 2/3*2/3*1/3 = 4/27$.

Similarly, $P(N=4) = 2/3*2/3*2/3*1/3 = 8/81$. Since these two events are mutually exclusive (they cannot happen at once), you can add probabilities to get $20/81$.